# spark spark.read().load().select().filter() vs spark.read().option(query) BIG time diference

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Hello I am working on a project where I have to pull data between 2018 and 2023. It's about 200 million records (not that many), But now I am confused with these two approaches to load data.

I did the query in oracle DB and it takes between 80 to 150 seconds.

Then I tried it like this with spark:

```
    DXHS_FACTURACION_CONSUMOS = spark.read \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", url_SGC_ORACLE) \
        .option("dbtable", 'DXHS_FACTURACION_CONSUMOS') \
        .option("user", username) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .option("driver", driver_oracle) \
        .load().select('ID_SERVICIO','ID_MES','CS_FACTURADO','CS_ANULADO','CS_REFACTURADO','IN_FACTURADO','CC_DIAS_FACTURADO','FE_FACTURA_ULTIMA') \
DXHS_FACTURACION_CONSUMOS.show()
```

It has been running for about 20 minutes and it does not finish, then I tried:

```
query2 = """
  SELECT ID_SERVICIO, ID_MES, CS_FACTURADO, CS_ANULADO, CS_REFACTURADO, IN_FACTURADO, CC_DIAS_FACTURADO, FE_FACTURA_ULTIMA FROM DXHS_FACTURACION_CONSUMOS WHERE ID_MES >=201801
"""

DXHS_FACTURACION_CONSUMOS = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url_SGC_ORACLE) \
    .option("query", query2) \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("driver", driver_oracle) \
    .load().alias('DXHS_FACTURACION_CONSUMOS')



DXHS_FACTURACION_CONSUMOS.show()
```

It takes about 90 seconds to finish.

Does the first example load the whole table and then it start filtering? while the second example filter first using the database and loads only the required data to spark? or why is it so big of a difference?

Thank you for the knowledge.

**Update:**

I am giving more context as some of you guys wanted it.

I am using spark 3.3.0 **LOCAL** mode. I tried to do the parallel reading as **Kashyap** mentioned but it looks like it only works in cluster mode and i would have to read the whole table.

This is an example of the table I am working with, i have data from 2000 or earlier but i just need from 2018 and onward.

I need to do a join with a similar table but with data from 2018 and onward.

| ID_SERVICIO | ID_MES | CS_FACTURADO | CS_ANULADO | CS_REFACTURADO | IN_FACTURADO | CC_DIAS_FACTURADO | FE_FACTURA_ULTIMA | TI_TARIFA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200001 | 324 | 0 | 0 | S | 31 | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 | c45 |
| 2 | 201801 | 425 | 20 | 0 | S | 31 | 2020-04-04 00:00:00 | g56 |
| 3 | 202212 | 645 | 0 | 56 | S | 28 | 2020-04-04 00:00:00 | f78 |

- It does not make sense to me that using select() and filter() has a different execution plan but it looks like it.
- As the tables are so big and i can't read in parallel because i have only one worker I did cache on both tables and then started working, but I do no know if it is better to cache after the first join is done. (I will test it)

thanks!

Comment: Can you perform an explain on the DXHS_FACTURACION_CONSUMOS daraframes and post the results here, it can be helpful to understand what's going on behind the scenes

Comment: @IVS Which Spark version are you using? Added my answer, let me know if it helps, if not I can help you investigate the cause

Answer (score 1):

- `.option("dbtable", 'DXHS_FACTURACION_CONSUMOS')` translates to `select * from DXHS_FACTURACION_CONSUMOS`.
- `.option("query", query2)` executes `query2` on DB, `SELECT <columns>.. WHERE ID_MES >=201801`.

Hence the first one is slower and second one is much faster, probably because of the where clause.

You're not using anything specific to Spark here.

If you do want to read large amount of data faster then use `partitionColumn` to [make Spark run multiple select queries](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) in parallel. E.g. you might be able to use year as the `partitionColumn` if you have it.

--- edit ---

> it looks like it only works in cluster mode with multiple workers

Yes and no. When you use `partitionColumn` in your code, spark generates a plan that contains multiple tasks (lets say 100), one each to execute a query like:

- `select * from table where partitionColumn > 0 and partitionColumn <= 100`
- `select * from table where partitionColumn > 100 and partitionColumn <= 200`
- ...
- `select * from table where partitionColumn > 9900 and partitionColumn <= 10000`

When it comes to actually executing this plan:

- if the HW you're running on has multiple executors (nodes) then the driver will execute these tasks in parallel.
- if the HW you're running on has a single executor (nodes) then the driver will execute these tasks one at a time.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it but i thought the execution plan should be basically the same. i did not know about partitionColumn and parallel reading,  it looks like it only works in cluster mode with multiple workers.

Comment: @IVS yes and no, updated the answer.